# Verify Proof that All Finite sets in order Field of Real numbers has a maximum and a minimum.

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I use the following facts:

1. The completeness axiom.
2. If supreme of a set an element the said set, then it is the maximum of the set.

Suppose S is finite non-empty set of real number. By the completeness axiom we are granted a supremum

exists for set. Call it is M. Assume as to acquire a contradiction that M is not in set S. Now take

any element s_1 in S. We must have s_1 < M, and hence there is s_2 in S such that s_1 < s_2

[note s_2 is not equal to M because of our assumption]

We may repeat the same argument over and over and generate infinitely many elements of S, which is

absurd because it is a finite set.

A similar argument should work for the case of a minimum.

Comment: You don't need the completeness axiom. Just argue by induction on the size of the set, using total ordering.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid induction purposely here. Sorry. I should have mentioned that. I just thought this argument was fun, but wasn't sure if it would be valid. Thanks.

Comment: To use completeness for the supremum, you need to know $S$ is bounded above. How would you prove that?

Comment: Good point! Finite sets have to be bounded. Perhaps via this reasoning. Suppose that a finite set wasn't bounded above. Then for any real number, we can find a element in S such that it is bigger than the real number we have chosen. Choose any real, say a. Then we can find s_1 such that r<s_1. Now pick real number s_1+1, which is larger than s_1 , and thus we can obtain s_2 such that s_1< s_2. We can then continue the process infinitely many times to arrive at the contraction that our set S is infinite, Or we can just assume that our set was bounded above from the start..